# Is it ok if I installed a cocoapod library in iOS project but never use it?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I installed `pod JSQMessagesViewController`in my Swift project but now I don't need it any more. I do not want to remove it to cause any side effect. Is it alright if I just leave it there and do nothing? Thanks!

Comment: What side effect would it cause? If removing a framework causes a breaking side effect then you have bigger issues to worry about than leaving an unused framework in your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it won't hurt anything.  However, it will make the binary larger than it should be due to unused libraries.  Also can be confusing later for others looking at the code why a particular library is there.  But, the app will not break because of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't making any reference to this framework it shouldn't cause any side effect if you remove it. I really recommend you to remove anything that is no longer used. It's a good practice to avoid problems with future iOS versions when building your project and also makes your app lighter for users with a quicker download.

Answer (score 0):

Just go ahead and remove the pod.

If you truly do not use it, your project will run without problems.

If you do actually use it without knowing about it, your app will most probably not compile, which is a great time to either remove the reference to the pod, or re-add it if you realize that you actually are using it.

If you do actually use it without knowing about it, your app may compile (e.g. if you refer to it from a xib or a storyboard), but will crash when trying to use the non-existing pod. This is much better than keeping on using the pod without knowing that it affects your project.

Good luck!